# Delete records using HeidiSQL based on count

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-delete, query-performance, mariadb-10.4

I have accidently created a large number (500K+) of incorrect records in a single table.
The table has Face_ID as the unique key, and Picture_ID as a foreign key.
I want to delete all records where there is a very large number of records linked to the same value of Picture_ID.
The following query works perfectly, and very quickly:

**`Select Picture_ID, COUNT(*) From faces Group BY Picture_ID Having COUNT(*) > 1000`**

I have tried the following, but event after 20 minutes of execution, the query is still running:

**`delete from faces where Picture_ID IN (Select Picture_ID From faces Group BY Picture_ID Having COUNT(*) > 1000)`**

Even if I adjust the number (1000 in the above example) to a value that finds only 3 values of Picture_ID, each with approximately 1000 records, the query still takes a very long time.
(Frankly, it scares me how long it takes - makes me wonder what will be left of my database when it finishes!)

What is the most efficient way to code this, using HeidiSQL and MariaDB on Windows 10.

Comment: add output of `show create table faces` and `explain delete from faces ... rest of your delete`

Comment: show create table faces:CREATE TABLE `faces` (
  `Face_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `X1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `X2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Y1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Y2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Person_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Picture_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FilePath` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Face_ID`),
  KEY `FK__people` (`Person_ID`),
  KEY `FK_faces_pictures` (`Picture_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=706450 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: I'm not sure what part you don't understand.        I am trying to delete records from the table faces, based on a selection of Picture_IDs.       The Picture_IDs are selected based on those Picture_IDs being linked to more than 1,000 records in the faces table.

Comment: can you show output of an EXPLAIN request please?  (edit your question and add it)   that should reveal what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

DELETE a
from faces a
JOIN
(Select Picture_ID From faces Group BY Picture_ID Having COUNT(*) > 1000) b
ON a.Picture_ID = b.Picture_ID

It works, and it is FAST!